# Unable to open model file for reading

Tags: java

I am new to java. I wanted to read the executable Jar file through command prompt. When i give the following command
Java -java "path.jar file"

It gives the error that unable to open model file for reading

I have model file but i dont know how to give path of that model file?

Comment: You think that all of us know what is your "model file"?

Answer (score 0):

You sound profoundly confused.  I think you might need to look at a simple tutorial to make sure you're doing things correctly on the command line.  I'll assume you're using Windows:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html